# Some applications ignore Xmodmap settings

Tags: keyboard, xkb, xmodmap

I am using the following `~/.Xmodmap`

```
keycode 133 = Mode_switch
keycode 134 = Mode_switch
keysym h = h H Left
keysym l = l L Right
keysym k = k K Up
keysym j = j J Down
keysym w = w W Prior
keysym s = s S Next
keysym a = a A Home
keysym d = d D End
keysym BackSpace = BackSpace BackSpace Delete
```

and it works as expected (eg. `Win+D` for `End`) for almost all applications, but not for PyCharm or IntelliJ. I suppose not for Java. How can that be fixed?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Ubuntu 18.04, X server 1.19.6, PyCharm 2018.3.4 running with OpenJDK 10.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a plugin (IdeaVim) that gets in the way. It works as expected with the plugin disabled.